# How to Derive this Formula for Expected n-Way Collisions?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I learned from the first answer to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24660/the-effect-of-truncated-hash-on-entropy (by formidable contributor fgrieu) that when $N$ uniform random selections are made from a finite set of $N$ elements, the probability that any particular element will be selected exactly $j$ times $\displaystyle\approx\frac 1{e\;j!}$, so the expected number of elements selected $j$ times $\displaystyle\approx\frac N{e\;j!}$.

The approximation is very rough for small $N$ and seems to converge gradually.  For sufficiently large $N$ (certainly by $10^9$) it works very well.

Contributor fgrieu even included the results of computational experiments for $N = 2^{35}$, confirming that this formula is very accurate for small $j$, and "breaks down" only when $j$ is near its maximum.

The author wrote that "we can establish" this expression "by counting of the possibilities."

I've been trying to derive the formula myself, and searched for a derivation online, so far without success.

I think I grasp the presence of fundamental constant $e$; for example, a classic gambler's problem asks "if the probability of winning a play is $\frac 1 n$, what is the probability of making $n$ plays without winning?"  The probability of losing each play is $1 - \frac 1 n$, so the probability of losing $n$ in a row is $\left( 1 - \frac 1 n \right)^n$, and $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac 1 n \right)^n = \frac 1 e$$ giving the asymptotic proportion of zero-win outcomes.

This also exactly accords with fgrieu's formula for the case $j=0$.

I've made no progress, however, justifying the formula's divisor $j!$.  I thought about $j!$ as the number of distinct *orderings* of selections of a given element in the sequence of $N$ selections, but didn't see that leading anywhere.  I enumerated every possible selection sequence for some tiny cases with very small $N$, looking for patterns in those sequences resulting in $j$-way collisions, without seeing the light.  [Exhaustive enumeration is a desperate exercise of size $N^N$; its appeal was that under the premise of uniform random selection every sequence is equally probable, so counting sequences with particular outcomes is a direct measure of probability.]

I've pondered the implicit recurrence that for $j > 0$, the probability a particular element will be selected exactly $j$ times equals $\frac 1 j $ times the probability it will be selected $j-1$ times ... but I have yet to find an explanation of why this must be so.

My intuition is that the derivation is simple, and I'm missing something that's right in front of me.  My thanks to any and all who will help me see it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you just need to count the possibilities.  There are $N^N$ possible selections. The number of favorable selections, where the distinguished element is chosen $j$ times, is $\binom Nj(N-1)^{N-j}$ because there are $\binom Nj$ ways to select which $j$ choices will be the distinguished element, and for each of the other $N-j$ choices we can choose any of the $N-1$ undistinguished elements.

The probability of success is
$$\begin{align}
\frac {\binom Nj (N-1)^{N-j}}{N^N}
&=\frac{N!(N-1)^{N-j}}{j!(N-j)!N^n}\\
&=\frac{N!}{j!(N-j)!(N-1)^j}\left(\frac{N-1}N\right)^N\\
&=\frac1{j!}\frac{N(N-1)\cdots(N-j+1)}{(N-1)^j}\left(1-\frac1N\right)^N
\end{align}$$

It's easy to see that this goes to $\frac1{j!e}$ as $N\to\infty$.  We have a constant term of $\frac1{j!}$ and you already know that the last term goes to $\frac1e$.  In the middle, we have $j$ terms of the form $\frac{N-k}{N-1}$ and each of these goes to $1$.